# Separate characters by dashes in vba

Tags: vba, excel, split

I am trying to separate characters by (-)dashes in VBA, then paste it to column B. So in my Column A I have TOM-JAY-MOE-XRAY. Now if I want to split it and paste into 4 different column like column B=TOM, C=JAY,so on. Here is my code and image to understand better.

[image]

```
Sub x()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For x = 1 To sheet.Range("A" & sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        sheet.Range("A", "B", "C", "D" & x) = InStr(1, sheet.Cells(x, 1), "-")
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
With Sheets("SheetName")
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & lr).TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("B1") _
        , DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="-"
End With
```

There is a built-in functionality in Excel to separate a delimited text, `TextToColumns`.
What we need is to just use that to separate the string especially if you only have 1 delimiter.

Actually, if you want all data in Column A to be evaluated, you don't need to check the last row with value. So below will work just fine.

```
With Sheets("SheetName")
    .Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("B1") _
        , DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="-"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split delimited text using the VBA `Split` function. Here is a basic example:

```
Sub test()

    Dim MyArray() As String

    ' use the VBA split function to split the string into array of strings
    ' the second function parameter identifies the delimiter
    MyArray() = Split("TOM-JAY-MOE-XRAY", "-")

    ' here I iterated the array and printed to the debug window.
    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        Debug.Print "Word " & i & "=" & MyArray(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it in one go (Even from the debug window) and is not restricted to being 4 columns (which is what you asked for in your post) but rather just takes up as many columns as it needs to based on how many - will split the string

```
Range("B9").Resize(1,ubound(Split(Range("A9").Text,"-"))+1) = Split(Range("A9").Text,"-")
```

My Test data was in row 9 column A, easy enough to drop this into a loop if you need to.

Note: This is provided as an alternative to other answers, I am not in any way saying this is the only or the best way to do it, if you are doing multiple rows you are best off using Excels inbuilt text to columns function as posted by @L42